# Get a process Owner (Citrix/Provisioning)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm using OpenProcessToken, GetTokenInformation and then LookupAccountSid to determine the owner of a certain process.

On a local machine (Win 7 and Win 8.1), on a RD Services session (Server 2012) it works fine. I do get the correct user name. The user name displayed in the task manager next to the process.

When I execute the same code in a Provisioning (ex Citrix) environment I only get the username "Administrator" although there is a different name displayed in the task manager.

Does anybody have an idea how to conquer this within a Provisioning environment?

Thanks a lot for any help
Martin

Here is the C++ Code I'm using:

```
BOOL DDEWinWord::processStartedFromLocalUser(DWORD procId)
{
    #define MAX_NAME 256
    DWORD dwSize = 0, dwResult = 0;
    HANDLE hToken;
    SID_NAME_USE SidType;
    char lpName[MAX_NAME];
    char lpDomain[MAX_NAME];
    PTOKEN_OWNER tp;

    // Open a handle to the access token for the calling process.
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procId);
    if (!OpenProcessToken(processHandle, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
        AfxMessageBox("processStartedFromLocalUser - OpenProcessToken fehlschlag.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Call GetTokenInformation to get the buffer size.
    if(!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, NULL, dwSize, &dwSize)) 
    {
        dwResult = GetLastError();
        if (dwResult != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            AfxMessageBox("processStartedFromLocalUser - GetTokenInformation fehlschlag.");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Allocate the buffer.
    tp = (PTOKEN_OWNER)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwSize);

    // Call GetTokenInformation again to get the group information.
    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOwner, tp, dwSize, &dwSize))
    {
        AfxMessageBox("processStartedFromLocalUser - GetTokenInformation mit tp fehlschlag.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!LookupAccountSid(NULL, tp->Owner, lpName, &dwSize, lpDomain, &dwSize, &SidType))
    {
        AfxMessageBox("processStartedFromLocalUser - LookupAccountSid fehlschlag."); 
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        AfxMessageBox(lpName);
    }

    return (m_stUserId.CompareNoCase(lpName) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `TokenUser` rather than `TokenOwner`.

Comment: What is the difference between those two? When are they different?

Comment: @maja: for administrator accounts, TokenOwner (which determines the default ownership of newly created objects) is by default set to Administrators rather than the specific user account.